# calling super() from an actionscript constructor with varargs

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, constructor, variadic-functions, super

If a constructor takes its parameters as a vararg (...) it seems to be impossible to create a subclass that will just pass on that vararg to the superclass.

There is a related question with fix for this same situation for normal functions: [Wrapping a Vararg Method in ActionScipt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509638/wrapping-a-vararg-method-in-actionscipt) but I cannot get that to work with a super call.

base class:

```
public class Bla
{
    public function Bla(...rest)
    {
        trace(rest[0]); // trace the first parameter
    }

}
```

subclass:

```
public class Blie extends Bla
{
    public function Blie(...rest)
    {
        // this is not working, it will 
        // pass an array containing all 
        // parameters as the first parameters
        super(rest); 
    }

}
```

if I now call

```
        var b1 = new Bla('d', 'e');
        var b2 = new Blie('a', 'b', 'c');
```

I get the output

```
d
a,b,c
```

And I want it to print out:

```
d
a
```

Aside from actually moving the handling of the parameters to the subclass or shifting it off to a separate initializer method, does anyone know how to get the super call right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's unfortunately no way to call the super constructor with `... args`. If you remove the `super()` call, it will be called by the compiler (with no arguments). `arguments` is also not accessible from constructors.

If you can change the method signatures, you modify the arguments to accept an `Array` rather than `... args`. Otherwise, as you mentioned, you could move it into an initializer method.

Comment: Hmm, not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks for confirming my suspicions.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a statement like this:

```
override public function doSomething(arg1:Object, ...args):void {
  switch(args.length) {
    case 0: super.doSomething(arg1); return;
    case 1: super.doSomething(arg1, args[0]); return;
    case 2: super.doSomething(arg1, args[0], args[1]); return;
  }
}
```